# I need help understanding java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I wrote code for caesar cipher but it's not working... Please help me solve this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("enter the String");
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        System.out.println("encrypting the String . . ." +str);

        for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
            for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
                if((char)i == str.charAt(j)){
                    str.setCharAt(j, (char)(i+3));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("encrypted String . . .");
    }
}
```

Here your solution works and no more java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
now there is another problem occured . . . .
I tried different inputs but all the time it replies same answer: ??????

Comment: `j<=str.length()` index are 0 based.

Comment: your suggestion solved my problem  . . .but now here occured an another error when I run the program it show the answer ?????                               I tried different inputs but every time there is only one output: ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++) // string index length are 0 based`

instead of

`for(int j=0; j<=str.length(); j++)`

Answer (score 1):

Strings in java are zero based. So you have to remove the `=` in your first loop:

```
for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
```

Answer (score 1):

String's character always start with index 0, it means if you store

```
String str="text";
```

then

```
str.charAt(0) // return "t"
str.charAt(1) // return "e"
str.charAt(2) // return "x"
str.charAt(3) // return "t"
```

and if you call `str.charAt(4)`

> it will throw java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException it means, the
>   index which you are targeting to get data from is out of bound.

So just change your for loop as everybody suggested.
Like this,

```
        for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
            for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
                if((char)i == str.charAt(j)){
                    str.setCharAt(j, (char)(i+3));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `j<= str.length()  to j< str.length()` in the `for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++)` as index starts from 0